# Sending/Receiving large data between webservice and console application

Tags: c#, .net, database, json, web-services

this is my first post on SO :)
I would like to communicate data, in this case from a DataTable over to a web service that saves to a database. I have tried different things. Through a 'Stream' with XML or a complete DataSet binary serialized and JSON recently. What I believe is that JSON might be the best option. By HttpWebRequest I send one line at a time from a DataTable with JSON to web service. The question is: Is this the best way to do it and how many connections will IIS manage? Do you have an alternative to the transmission of larger data to "sync" with another database through a webservice? I have read alot of posts on SO and don't find what I'm looking for.

I want a reliable transportation structure that doesn't timeout or waste connections/bandwidth.

Comment: What do you consider "large data?"

Comment: Around 400-600MB, maybe more. But sometimes even less. It's a "sync" operation, client downloads and uploads information via webservice. A total "sync" might be >600MB.

Comment: Forgot :) sometimes a collection of images as well...

Comment: Wow, that is insane!  I really don't think a web service interface is best for this scenario.  I don't know how many "lines" you have for 400-600MB, but that is a lot of calls back and forth, and a lot of overhead.  What if your web service simply create a "token" of some sort, returns that to the client, and you use some FTP calls to send the data, then send a "completed" call to the web service to process?

Comment: I thought of that, the client can download the information but how do I do that from the server side to get updates from each client? This is a self developed CRM client/server solution that used to connect directly to a DB, but now we want it to "sync" through webservices.

Comment: Are all your clients "DotNet" clients?  Or heterogeneous?